# Upload Photos in 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04

I will be new to Ubuntu in a couple weeks.  I am currently a WindowsXP user.  So, my question is: Does Ubuntu 12.04.4 have a utility that will allow me to upload photos from a smartphone(BB) and a digital camera(Nikon)?  If so, how well does it work and should I be aware of any glitches?

Please advise.
Franco

Comment: Actually most of devices work out of box in Ubuntu, you plug it in system recognizes it and asks what you want to do. After that shotwell default photo manager in Ubuntu can upload to various online services, or you can manage your photos at your will.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for Ubuntu One. It's Ubuntu's cloud service and it works fine for me ^_^ You can also try dropbox but I don't know how integrated it is.

**More information and downloads:**
Ubuntu One: https://one.ubuntu.com/ 
Dropbox: http://www.dropbox.com/

Comment: How this actually answers OP question?